# Why data results showed twice while trying to load data from localStorage and API without using useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Here is part of my project where I have tried to load data from my localStorage and to load data from jsonplaceholder(this is for the sake of my enquiry, it is not part of my main project):

```
//load data from local storage and API without using useEffect
  const savedCart = getDatabaseCart();
    console.log(savedCart);
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));

//load data from local storage and API using useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    const savedCart = getDatabaseCart();
    console.log(savedCart);
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  }, []);
```

and the results are here: the first result appears when I don't apply useEffect, the second result comes when I apply useEffect---->
[image: this is the result without using useEffect]

[image: this causes while applying useEffect]

why is this happening???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is caused by a rerender (state updated somewhere else). The useEffect hook with the empty second parameter causes the handler to only run once. Here's more information: css-tricks.com/run-useeffect-only-once